# using RawPrinterHelper Print the other Langauge Characters rather than english

Tags: c#

I need to print Tamil or Hindi characters using RawPrinterHelper How we can do it. I try

Print(eInit + 'நன்றி');

```
     public void Print(string Line)
     {
         prn.SendStringToPrinter(PrinterName, Line);
     }

     public bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
     {
         bool functionReturnValue = false;
         if (PrinterOpen)
         {
             IntPtr pBytes = default(IntPtr);
             Int32 dwCount = default(Int32);
             Int32 dwWritten = 0;
             dwCount = szString.Length;
             pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
             functionReturnValue = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, ref dwWritten);
             Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
         }
         else
         {
             functionReturnValue = false;
         }
         return functionReturnValue;
     }
```

It is does not work

Comment: What is `RawPrinterHelper`? It's not part of the BCL.

Comment: You're also using `StringToCoTaskMemAnsi`, which, as the name suggests, only handles ANSI characters.

Comment: So how we can do it can you help me please

Comment: I don't know what "it" is, because I don't know what `RawPrinterHelper` or `WritePrinter` are. Please read [ask] and make sure that you include a [mcve] (with emphasis on "reproducible") in your question

Comment: You are using the wrong string encoding. Instead of ANSI, you should use UTF-8, for example. Instead of `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi`, just try `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUTF8`

Comment: The kind of printer where this code is useful invariably implements *character sets*.  You have to send the command to switch to desired code page, then send bytes that represent the glyph you want from the set.  [Example](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf)